# Bootstrap Dropdown Две кнопки - работает последняя

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, dropdown

Есть две кнопки. Первая - авторизация. Вторая - поиск. Почему-то срабатывает последняя, выполняя две функции сразу. Помещены они в один класс:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

Пробовал помещать их в разные классы, в таком случае работает только последняя (search). Что тут от чего зависит? Как заставить их две выполнять разные функции?
[image: Скрин]

Код:

```
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">


<li class="dropdown">
<li class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in auth" aria-hidden="true"></span></li></li>
<ul class="dropdown-menu downauth">
<li>
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</li>
</ul>
</li>

 <li class="dropdown">
<li class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search iconsearch" aria-hidden="true"></span></li>
<ul class="dropdown-menu search">
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left classsearch" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search icon3" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go!</button> -->
      </form>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Код ваш давайте. А то тут можно только гадать.

Comment: Добавил. Вначале форма авторизации, потом форма поиска. Я сейчас  дополнительные классы не вписывал т.к. они не решают проблему.

Comment: а где у кнопок id и aria-labelledby у выпадающих блоков?

Comment: В каком конкретно месте нужно добавить id ?

Comment: А вот это что за ерунда в конце пятой строки? /li /li

Comment: Закрыл саму кнопку и span в котором иконка бутстрапа.

Comment: бардак. так нельзя вообще-то... li это элемент списка, в него нельзя вкладывать еще один элемент списка. можно новый список...

Comment: Убрал. Теперь при нажатии на каждую кнопку срабатывают сразу две, как на картинке. Уже ближе к цели)

Comment: Надо их как-то разделить, добавил бы разные классы, но куда?

Comment: Дополнительные классы к значкам есть, а при добавлении к "dropdown" ничего не меняется

Comment: у меня ваш когда не работает, когда в codepen его пытаюсь крутить. так-что могу посоветовать вам вначале разобрать со всякими левыми вложеностями. я вообще не понимаю зачем вам столько списков, делайте как в документации к bootstrap, зачем этот изврат?

Comment: Так это чисто из документации. Просто еще добавлена иконка внутрь и всё.

Comment: Правда? Смотрю - не вижу http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Comment: Ну вот) Такая же кнопка, просто вложен код для поиска и авторизации  )

Comment: Короче говоря разобрался. У вас ошибка вложенности. Вы закрываете теги не там где нужно. Во второй меню - ацкий трэш.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in auth" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu downauth">
      <li>
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search iconsearch" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu search">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left classsearch" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search icon3" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Да, работает отлично) Спасибо большое ) Надо будет разобраться детально где и чего не хватало в моем коде.